Bootstrap 5 - How to apply :hover effect on the top "Home" <li> 100% width when menu is collapsed
When the nav bar collapses for mobile devices I would like to have the :hover effect on the top menu option "Home" to apply across the top bar 100% wide. So the hover color is behind the toggler button.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/R-P-P/pen/zxOdyJb?editors=1100


.navbar .nav-link {
    padding: 10px 8px 12px 8px !important;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: White;
}
 .navbar .nav-link:hover {
    color: red; 
}
#nav-home:hover {background-color: #ffffff;} 
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Home Hover</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xxl navbar-dark row g-0 m-0 p-0" style="background-color: rgb(150 150 150) !important;">
  
    <div class="container m-0 p-0">
       <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" id="nav-home"><a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a></li>
       </ul>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
</body>
</html>




Update
CSS
After making a JavaScript answer I realized I can resolve the issues with CSS so now there's CSS solution as well. The biggest obstacle was that space between #nav-home and .navbar-toggler so once #nav-home was stretched out, there was no need to change the background of any ancestor.
JavaScript
The required hover behavior for #nav-home and .navbar-toggler with CSS is not worth the trouble (even if it's possible). Since they're both descendants of .container and .navbar it was possible to either have #nav-home's behavior or .navbar-toggler's behavior but not both because the ancestors' must be included in the selector so the space between #nav-home and .navbar-toggler was properly colored.
The final solution was to give #mynavbar an inline style to protect it's yellow background from inheriting the purple hover background and then use JavaScript to delegate pointerEvents fired on #nav-home and .navbar-toggler then toggle the background of .box✳ from yellow to purple and vice versa. The width of #nav-home is stretched to the side of .navbar-toggler, now it feels more comfortable having the link being more than half the width of it's "sibling" links (I know they are not siblings but they certainly look related).
I realized that when I was referring to #nav-home I really meant it's parent ul.navbar-nav:first-of-type not catchy.
✳Added .box class to .container because Bootstrap pages usually have a top tier element with the .container class.
CSS


.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(251 152 5);
}

.navbar .nav-link {
  font: 500 19px "roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  padding-block: 6px !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 10px 8px 12px 8px !important;
}

#nav-link1:hover {
  background-color: #0200ac;
}

#nav-link2:hover {
  background-color: #05bd08;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #nav-social-follow {
    text-align: left;
  }

  #nav-social-share {
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.flex-grow-1:hover,
.flex-grow-1:hover + .navbar-toggler {
  background-color: #91008b;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler:hover {
  background-color: #fb9805;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xxl row g-0 m-0 p-0">
    <div class="box d-flex container m-0 p-0">
      <ul class="flex-grow-1 navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" id="nav-home"><a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item" id="nav-link1"><a class="nav-link" href="">Link1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" id="nav-link2"><a class="nav-link" href="">Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>



JavaScript


const lnk = document.querySelector("#nav-home");
const ico = document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler-icon");

const hoverHome = event => {
  const tgt = event.target;
  let mod = tgt.matches("#nav-home");
  const box = document.querySelector(".box");
  let colors = ["#91008b", "#fb9805"];
  const action = event.type;
  
  switch (action) {
    case "pointermove":
      event.preventDefault();
      break;
    case "pointerenter":
      box.style.backgroundColor = mod ? colors[0] : colors[1];
      break;
    case "pointerleave":
      box.style.backgroundColor = colors[1];
      break;
  }
};

lnk.addEventListener("pointerenter", hoverHome);
lnk.addEventListener("pointermove", hoverHome);
lnk.addEventListener("pointerleave", hoverHome);

ico.addEventListener("pointerenter", hoverHome);
ico.addEventListener("pointermove", hoverHome);
ico.addEventListener("pointerleave", hoverHome);
.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(251 152 5);
}

.navbar .nav-link {
  font: 500 19px "roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}


.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 10px 8px 12px 8px !important;
}

#nav-link1:hover {
  background-color: #0200ac;
}

#nav-link2:hover {
  background-color: #05bd08;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #nav-social-follow {
    text-align: left;
  }

  #nav-social-share {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xxl row g-0 m-0 p-0">
    <div class="box d-flex container m-0 p-0">
      <ul class="flex-grow-1 navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" id="nav-home"><a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar" style="background-color: #fb9805">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item" id="nav-link1"><a class="nav-link" href="">Link1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" id="nav-link2"><a class="nav-link" href="">Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>




Thank you for the reply and time to have a look at this.
The color doesn't matter in this example. If I can get this to work I will edit the colors.
This did sort of worked however, when I click down the nav via the "hamburger" icon and hover over the "Home" , the hover color shows but then does not go away changing the however color of the entire list. The expected result should only effect the "Home" .

The update get's up really close.
Is there a way for the entire "Home" row to show the color upon :hover, not either the "Home" link or the area the toggler is on?
On my working nav bar, I have all the 's show a "hover color. The only row that was not showing a "hover color 100% across the row is the "Home" area.
Thank you again for your help.
Bootsrap was not my first choice in doing this. I actually had the nav designed using div's only but could not figure out how to have the nav collapse with a "Hamburger" on a media query.

Can you post the list of hover behaviors on your question? I'm having a hard time following the comments.

Absolutely. I stripped down the nav I am working on for my site. Here is the codepen link.
https://codepen.io/R-P-P/pen/dPbVodv?editors=1100
FYI - I like your binary bio.

I meant like a list on your question: 1. when home is hovered on back-color: #fc1 and navbar is same. 2. ...and so on. A list of how each component should react when hovered and if it's relevant how they are when not on a mobile.

Does this help?
https://codepen.io/R-P-P/pen/dPbVodv?editors=1100
The "Home" and "Toggler" should function as is however, somehow I'd like to tie :hover to apply to the entire row if the user hovers anywhere over the row except the "Toggler" icon.
FYI - I like your binary bio. I was a network professional in a prior life and had a very similar bio in binary in some areas of the interwebs.

Thanks, TBH I don't even remember what it translated to. I see so if the hamburger is hovered over then nothing changes.

"I code therefore I am."
Correct - " so if the hamburger is hovered over then nothing changes." The hamburger will expand/collapse the nav but not change the background-color.

Oh yeah, that was ages. Since you have non-Bootstrap colors you should remove .navbar-dark from <nav> The yellow background is now in the CSS so now you don't need the style="...!important" override. Basically you can change anything while hovering but you'll need to place the :hover on .navbar then the selector of the element you intend to change. See updated example.

Great tips. It is almost there.

The purple hover color "Home" should also be the color behind "Toggler" icon. So, the entire row when hover is active is the purple color.
When the user is not hovering over the 'Home" row, the default color should show. See when the nav expands down, the "Home" hover color still shows.

I will make the non-bootstrap edits on the working nav.

What color is "Home" hovered expanded? I just updated and it is purple at any screen size when hovered.

The default orange color.

It all looks good except when the navbar shows the hamburger, the hover effect on "Home" should only work when hovered. When not hovered the "Home" row should not show the hover color. Other than that it looks good. I also looks like the color fo the "Toggler" icon changed in making these edits.

"When not hovered the "Home" row should not show the hover color." OK, I'm confused, instead of saying "hover color" please say the actual color like, "When not hovered the "Home" row should not show purple."

I apologize.

When the menu is in "Hamburger" mode and the user hovers over the "Home" row, upon hover "purple" shows.
When the cursor is moved away from the "Home" row, "rgb(251 152 5)" the row should be "rgb(251 152 5)".

The "Home" row hover effect should act the same as "Link1" and "Link2" row.
I hope this is more clear. :)
https://codepen.io/R-P-P/pen/dPbVodv

"The "Home" row hover effect should act the same as "Link1" and "Link2" row" If I Remember correctly all 3 links had a unique hover color purple, navy, and green? So they never change?

Correct, each row has their own color.

OK when home is hovered upon it will be purple but not the whole bar when the viewport is large. When home is hovered over and the viewport is small both home and navbar are purple.
